# How can I add a attachment field to my new form list

Tags: attachments

I have the setting checked yes for attachments.
Then I click on the edit tab above then attach file, once I attach the file, it disappears and I cant see it after the record is saved.
So how would I add a attachment to a record?

Comment: What version of Sharepoint are you using? You should be adding the attachment through the ribbon, when you create a New item or Edit an existing item. Once you save, you should be able to see the attachment listed on the View item.

Comment: 2010, when I click attach file, the browse button appears on the bottom of my site, then I attaché but cant view it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to do it.

- One is create a hidden field in the list named Attachments, and with
  the help of event receiver, set it when attachment added, updated,
  deleted. So, now you have the attachment names (if needed add them as
  links, for this the column must be of type multi line text box (rich
  text field)).
- Second and easiest way is the modifications using SharePoint
  Designer. Just follow this steps mentioned [here](http://amitphule.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html)